# Firebase sign in user disconnects from internet

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

When a user is logging in and he turn of the mobile data or wi-fi my application crash. How can I check while the process is running if the user is still connected to the Internet or somehow handle this error.
Thank you in advance and I'm sorry for my English.

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, UserPassword)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            startActivity(new Intent(LogIn.this, MainActivity.class));
                            Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Logged in succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException) task.getException();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "LogIn failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                       Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

**UPDATE**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException
                                                                                                at com.example.mypc.ex.LogInRegister.LogIn$2.onComplete(LogIn.java:104)
                                                                                                at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

**UPDATE v2**

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, UserPassword)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                startActivity(new Intent(LogIn.this, MainActivity.class));
                                Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Logged in succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                FirebaseException e = (FirebaseException) task.getException();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "LogIn failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting a sample code would help clarify your problem, but generally speaking you can always catch non-runtime exceptions and handle it.

So the part of your code that executes the connection to firebase, wrap it with try catch block. Print out the error message in log, and then figure out a logic to let the user know depends on that message thrown in that exception.

Edit:
I see the problem now after updating your post:

```
                   else {
                            FirebaseAuthException e = (FirebaseAuthException) task.getException();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "LogIn failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
```

Here you are assuming that the exception is always `FirebaseAuthException` and you can see in the log that it is `FirebaseNetworkException`

Here is how it should be

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, UserPassword)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            try{
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(LogIn.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Logged in succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                         .show();
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (FirebaseAuthException | FirebaseNetworkException e){
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "LogIn failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
    }
```

Comment: I posted it. addOnFailureListener shouldn't catch it? It still says Unfortunately, appname has stopped.

Comment: The code looks fine, Can you post the log of the crash?

Comment: When the user click on sign in button, I check if he's connected to the internet, but while the process is running I turn off the wi-fi, then I got that error.

Comment: Alright I see the problem I will post it in the answer

Comment: Check my answer, you can adjust the error handling to your needs

Comment: I just change FirebaseAuthException to FirebaseException and it works. Thank you!